# PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR LIKE operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In my Rails project i get this error, when i trying to make rating.

Error:

> PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer ~~
>   integer LINE 1: ...dbacks" WHERE "feedbacks"."user_id" = $1 AND
>   (rating LIKE 5) ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and
>   argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. : SELECT
>   COUNT(*) FROM "feedbacks" WHERE "feedbacks"."user_id" = $1 AND (rating
>   LIKE 5)

Controller Code:

```
unless @user.feedbacks.count == 0
  @rating = ((@user.feedbacks.where("rating LIKE 5").count*5 + @user.feedbacks.where("rating LIKE 4").count*4 +
  @user.feedbacks.where("rating LIKE 3").count*3 +
  @user.feedbacks.where("rating LIKE 2").count*2
 +@user.feedbacks.where("rating LIKE 1").count).to_f / @user.feedbacks.count).round(2)
else
  @rating = 0
end
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`The PostgreSQL documentation`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html):

> The LIKE expression returns true if the **string** matches the supplied
>   pattern. (As expected, the NOT LIKE expression returns false if LIKE
>   returns true, and vice versa. An equivalent expression is NOT (string
>   LIKE pattern).)

You can't use the `LIKE` operator with the integer. Edit your query.
Something like this:

```
"rating = 5"
```

Comment: Thx you! It works. I changed this "rating LIKE 5" to "rating = 5".

Comment: Please do not write a comment like this one or _Cool!_. If this resolves your problem, mark the answer as accepted. Happy coding!